# scrollTop animation caused white flash of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed menu at the top of my screen with 4 option, each option when clicked will scroll to a section within the page. The code I am using is as follows:

```
$("#click1").click(function (){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#sec1").offset().top}, 1000);
});
```

The scroll works as expected but when I click the options I get a flash of a white page. Has one else seen this and know any solution. Not sure if it's caused by the fixed menu element on the page.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Would need to see more of your code to determine anything. Can you reproduce this issue in a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue before. Try this:

```
$("#click1").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#sec1").offset().top}, 1000);
    });
```

Here is the jQuery API: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Excellent Marcel W, that's the one!